Generate and repeat NEWID() values in a single query
I am trying to generate and then duplicate multiple UNIQUEIDENTIFIER values using NEWID() for use as test data. The following is my attempt is to first generate N1 values and then use a CROSS APPLY to duplicate these values N2 times each:
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        S1.value,
        NEWID() AS Id
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 3) S1
) S1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        S2.value,
        S1.Id -- Trying to repeat the same ID value multiple times
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 2) S2
) S2
ORDER BY S1.Value, S2.Value

Desired results:



value
Id
value
Id




1
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb
1
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb


1
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb
2
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb


1
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb
3
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb


2
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e
1
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e


2
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e
2
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e


2
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e
3
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e



Actual results:



value
Id
value
Id




1
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb
1
26d1f8c0-05e8-4d6f-91ab-f97ce13f79fb


1
8dbf1b38-f6af-4b7e-9b3d-65f3df4bb017
2
8dbf1b38-f6af-4b7e-9b3d-65f3df4bb017


1
2eddb5e1-4f3e-4938-ab7b-49740a20a779
3
2eddb5e1-4f3e-4938-ab7b-49740a20a779


2
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e
1
4743c229-0c3c-44fd-b9f8-9406b06e350e


2
f8a66f07-04da-44ab-af7b-47a747dc6bf6
2
f8a66f07-04da-44ab-af7b-47a747dc6bf6


2
034876b6-8cf5-4264-810d-de5202554d77
3
034876b6-8cf5-4264-810d-de5202554d77



I understand that NEWID() will generate unique values for each row where it is used, but I would have thought that when used in a subquery, the values would be generated in that subquery instead of being generated at the outermost level. I can't find a clear explanation if this behavior in the NEWID documentation or elsewhere.
I tried inserting intermediate calculations using CAST(), TOUPPER(), and REPLACE(), which I thought might capture and solidify the NEWID() values. I also tries wrapping the first part up in a CTE. I still cannot get the generated values to repeat.
I can do this in multiple steps using a #temp table or @table variable, but I was just wondering if there is a way to accomplish this in a single statement.
db<>fiddle
Here's another similar case:
-- Another similar case
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT NEWID() AS Id -- Is this one value or many?
)
SELECT *
FROM ( VALUES (1), (2), (3) ) ID(Id)
CROSS JOIN CTE

Follow-up:
I discovered a similar question on dba stackexchange that pointed me to a 15 year old Microsoft Connect bug report and discussion, that ended up with the bug report being closed as won't-fix, functions-as-designed. The rationale is that, "the optimizer does not guarantee timing or number of executions of scalar functions", and "it's quite hard to pin down precisely ... what once-per-row behavior means."
That same post had a late comment that found a workaround using a combination of GROUP BY and FULL OUTER JOIN to coax the desired behavior, but later comments suggest that this was still undefined behavior.
I also found some 2005 old books-online documentation that includes a best practice: "Limit uses of nondeterministic functions to outermost select lists." I could not find the same in the  current documentation, but may not have been looking in the right place.
So although ValNik's answer below suggests a workaround involving GROUP BY, I think that is also think that is built on unstable ground. (ValNik's answer actually begins with a "does not make sense" comment.)
I also discovered that adding an IS NOT NULL check also coaxes the desired result (fiddle). Again this is likely undefined behavior that just seems to work - best avoided.
Bottom line, it is probably best to follow the old "Limit uses of nondeterministic functions to outermost select lists" practice, which means selecting into a temp table or table variable as Thom A recommended and nbk documented as an answer.

Use a temporary table, rather than a CTE.

Thanks @ThomA, but I was aware of that option. I was wondering if there is a way to control the evaluation so that this could be accomplished in a single statement.

As far as I know, newid will return a different value per execution, not per row.

You cannot control how/when SQL server evaluates sub expressions. It could evaluate your original query as follows without breaking any rules:
SELECT S1.value, NEWID() AS Id, S2.value
FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 3) S1
CROSS APPLY GENERATE_SERIES(1, 2) S2
ORDER BY S1.value, S2.value

The NEWID function gets called 3 x 2 times to get 6 different values.
Using temporary tables to store the newid values is the correct thing to do.

I think, an intermediate grouping, which does not make sense in itself, can change the order of query execution (cause output to stream and then join) and give the expected result.
In my example, the result obtained differs from the one indicated as desired by you (S1.Value<->S2.Value). But these details are not so important.
See example
SELECT *
FROM (
  select  max(Value) Value, id
  from(
     SELECT
        S1.value ,
        NEWID() AS Id
     FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 3) S1
  )x
    group by id
) S1
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT
        S2.value,
        S1.Id 
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 2) S2
) S2
ORDER BY S1.Value, S2.Value

Output



Value
id
value
Id




1
feacc54f-aa9d-4344-ac87-f6312fa53a86
1
feacc54f-aa9d-4344-ac87-f6312fa53a86


1
feacc54f-aa9d-4344-ac87-f6312fa53a86
2
feacc54f-aa9d-4344-ac87-f6312fa53a86


2
a315222a-1408-4ff3-a29d-4106b655299c
1
a315222a-1408-4ff3-a29d-4106b655299c


2
a315222a-1408-4ff3-a29d-4106b655299c
2
a315222a-1408-4ff3-a29d-4106b655299c


3
ce32abfe-74c6-467f-9dbb-23d8574a9e59
1
ce32abfe-74c6-467f-9dbb-23d8574a9e59


3
ce32abfe-74c6-467f-9dbb-23d8574a9e59
2
ce32abfe-74c6-467f-9dbb-23d8574a9e59



Fiddle
Plans

and


Thanks for the work, but after some additional research (see question addendum), I think the better answer is don't try to make nested NEWID()'s work down inside a nested query, and go with a separate query into a temp table.

@TN, thanks for usefull investigation. undefined behavior - is important argument.

As Thom_a suggested in his comment
Y
better suited is a temporary table which you can CROSs APPLY
 SELECT
        S1.value,
        NEWID() AS Id
   INTO #S1
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 2) S1;
  
 SELECT
  

   #S1.value,#S1.Id,
           S2.value,
        #S1.Id as CTEID -- Trying to repeat the same value multiple times
    FROM GENERATE_SERIES(1, 3) S2 CROSS APPLY #S1





value
Id
value
CTEID




1
be7c07b1-4beb-4e64-81bf-5348019e33e6
1
be7c07b1-4beb-4e64-81bf-5348019e33e6


1
be7c07b1-4beb-4e64-81bf-5348019e33e6
2
be7c07b1-4beb-4e64-81bf-5348019e33e6


1
be7c07b1-4beb-4e64-81bf-5348019e33e6
3
be7c07b1-4beb-4e64-81bf-5348019e33e6


2
98dbfd30-ac7f-4b90-977f-5671248a6333
1
98dbfd30-ac7f-4b90-977f-5671248a6333


2
98dbfd30-ac7f-4b90-977f-5671248a6333
2
98dbfd30-ac7f-4b90-977f-5671248a6333


2
98dbfd30-ac7f-4b90-977f-5671248a6333
3
98dbfd30-ac7f-4b90-977f-5671248a6333



fiddle
